# What is the result of the following integral including Wasserstein distance?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, optimal-transport

For two probability measure $\pi_1=\frac{\delta_0+\delta_1}{2}$ and $\nu=\frac{\delta_0+\delta_1+\delta_2}{3}$, why do we have the 1-Wasserstein distance
$$
W_1(\pi_1,\nu)=\frac{1}{2}?
$$

Also, for $\pi_2=\delta_2$, why do we have $W_1(\pi_2,\nu)=1$? What is the result of the following integral for $x_1=1,2$,
$$
\int W(\pi_{x_1},\nu)d\mu(x_1)
$$
Is it equal to $1\times W(\pi_1,\nu)+2\times W(\pi_2,\nu)=\frac{1}{2}+2?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider the simpler case $W_1(\pi_2, \nu) = 1$. Consider the coupling $(X, Y)$, where we take $X \sim \pi_2$ and $Y \sim \nu$ independent of each other. Then because $X = 2$ almost surely, we have $\mathbb{E}|X - Y| = 1 \times \nu(1) + 2 \times \nu(0) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} = 1$. Since $W_1(\pi_2, \nu)$ is the infimum over all such couplings $(X, Y)$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$, we have $W_1(\pi_2, \nu) \leq 1$. To obtain a lower bound of the same value, consider moving all the mass of $\pi_2$ (which is concentrated on $2$) to obtain $\nu$ (which is uniform over $\{0, 1, 2\}$). Intuitively, we must move at least $\frac{2}{3}$ mass to $\{0, 1\}$, and since $1$ has capacity $\frac{1}{3}$, we must move at least $\frac{1}{3}$ mass to $0$. So any coupling $(X, Y)$ must have $\mathbb{E}|X - Y| \geq 1$. Thus $W_1(\pi_2, \nu) = \inf_{(X, Y) \sim (\pi_2, \nu)} \mathbb{E}|X - Y| = 1$.

A similar argument yields $W_1(\pi_1, \nu) = \frac{1}{2}$. We can exhibit the optimal coupling (which gives the upper bound). Let $\mathbb{P}(X = Y = 0) = \frac{1}{3}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X = Y = 1) = \frac{1}{3}$; i.e. the minimum over the common support of $\pi_1$ and $\nu$. To fill in the remaining mass, let $\mathbb{P}(X = 0, Y = 2) = \mathbb{P}(X = 1, Y =2) = \frac{1}{6}$. Under this coupling, we have $\mathbb{E}|X - Y| = 1 \times \frac{1}{6} + 2 \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$. An analogous argument as the simpler case above shows that this is also the matching lower bound. Hence $W_1(\pi_1, \nu) = \frac{1}{2}$.

The result of your integral depends on what $\mu$ is (apparently some measure supported on $\{ 1, 2 \}$): $\int W(\pi_{x_1}, \nu) \,\mathrm{d} \mu(x_1) = W(\pi_1, \nu) \cdot \mu(1) + W(\pi_2, \nu) \cdot \mu(2)$.

Comment: Sorry $x\in \{2\}$. So the integral is $|2-1|\times \pi(2,1)+|2-0|\pi(2,0)$ But it seems that $\pi(2,1)=\mu(2)\times \nu(1)$? So that is $1\times \pi(2)\nu(1)+2\mu(2)\nu(0)=1$.

Comment: Oh I see. But why the coupling of two Dirac measures must be the product measure? (i.e., $\pi(2,1)$ must be $\mu(2)\times \nu(1)$?

Comment: Also, for $W_1(\pi_1,\nu)$, I try to compute $E|X-Y|$, that is $1\times \pi(0,1)+2\times \pi(0,2)+\pi(1,0)+\pi(1,2)$. So I got a wrong result $5/6$? Is there any problems?

Comment: For the second case, why not consider $X=0, Y=1$?

Comment: Questions from bottom up. 1) We've already exhausted the probability mass for $Y = 1$, so you can think of $X = 0, Y = 1$ occurring with probability zero. 2) You should check your calculation again (it should be what I've written down). 3) It doesn't have to be the product measure, but in this simple case I only want to exhibit a particular coupling that achieves the Wasserstein distance. (In fact, the second coupling for $W_1(\pi_1, \nu)$ is not a product measure.)